# Brute Force on Whole Disk Encryption

Tags: macos, password, encryption

I'm helping someone that changed their password (Thanks to corporate policy) and then forgot what they set it to. They remember the first part so I would not need to completely  brute force it. I was thinking about booting into recovery mode and trying to run some kind of script from bash to try to unlock the partition (diskutil corestorage unlockvolume UUID -passphrase PASSWORD) using different passwords until successful.

1. Is there a better approach?
2. If this is an okay approach... Does anyone know of any scripts that would do this kin of thing?

Comment: Is the password going to be english words only? You can try your luck with a dictionary attack, as it's a lot easier than brute force. Just 5 random letters (only lower case) have a keyspace of ~1.2m possibilities.

Comment: Are you using Filevault 2?

Comment: The person I'm helping remembered their password after many attempts. I will just leave this question up for others that might be in this situation. Maybe someone out there has a good answer.